# select the value from another field when the selected field is empty

Tags: ms-access

In ms-access, I want to select the value from another field when the selected field is empty.
So when the owner is empty I want the Managers name to be selected.

```
SELECT

    [Master Bench Assignments].Active,
    [Client/Projects].Client,
    Employees.[Last Name],
    Employees.[First Name],
    [Client/Projects].Project,
    [Bench Assignments].Name,
    [Bench Assignments].[Long Description],
    [Master Bench Assignments].Notes,
    [Bench Assignments].Owner,
    [Staff Managers].[Last Name]
FROM [Client/Projects]

    RIGHT JOIN ([Staff Managers] 
        RIGHT JOIN (Employees RIGHT JOIN ([Bench Assignments] 
            LEFT JOIN [Master Bench Assignments] ON [Bench Assignments].[Bench ID] = [Master Bench Assignments].[Bench Task ID]) ON Employees.[Employee ID] = [Master Bench Assignments].[Employee ID]) 
        ON [Staff Managers].[Staff Manager ID] = Employees.[Staff Manager ID]) 
    ON [Client/Projects].[Project ID] = [Master Bench Assignments].[Client/Project]
WHERE ((([Master Bench Assignments].Active)=Yes) 
    AND (([Master Bench Assignments].Status)="Bench")) 

ORDER BY [Bench Assignments].Name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example which demonstrates what I think you want to do.

```sql
SELECT
    p.owner,
    p.manager,
    Nz(p.owner, p.manager) AS the_decider
FROM Projects AS p;
```

This is the output from that query with a 2 row sample table:

```
owner manager the_decider
----- ------- -----------
a     b       a
      c       c
```

If you will be running the query from outside an Access session, you can use `IIf` instead of `Nz`.

```
IIf(p.owner Is Null, p.manager, p.owner) AS the_decider
```

Comment: Good note about running outside Access. That can be a real gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`Nz`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php) function. It is like `IsNull` or `coalesce`

```
SELECT

    [Master Bench Assignments].Active,
    [Client/Projects].Client,
    Employees.[Last Name],
    Employees.[First Name],
    [Client/Projects].Project,
    [Bench Assignments].Name,
    [Bench Assignments].[Long Description],
    [Master Bench Assignments].Notes,
    Nz([Bench Assignments].Owner, [Staff Managers].[Last Name]) as [columnName]
    [Staff Managers].[Last Name]
FROM [Client/Projects]

    RIGHT JOIN ([Staff Managers] 
        RIGHT JOIN (Employees RIGHT JOIN ([Bench Assignments] 
            LEFT JOIN [Master Bench Assignments] ON [Bench Assignments].[Bench ID] = [Master Bench Assignments].[Bench Task ID]) ON Employees.[Employee ID] = [Master Bench Assignments].[Employee ID]) 
        ON [Staff Managers].[Staff Manager ID] = Employees.[Staff Manager ID]) 
    ON [Client/Projects].[Project ID] = [Master Bench Assignments].[Client/Project]
WHERE ((([Master Bench Assignments].Active)=Yes) 
    AND (([Master Bench Assignments].Status)="Bench")) 

ORDER BY [Bench Assignments].Name;
```